# PDF file downloaded from API returns blank

Tags: node.js, pdf, postman

I'm downloading a PDF file from the Typeform API. I tried getting an output via Postman and managed to download the file without problem.
However, when I try to download it with this code it returns a blank PDF:

`fs.writeFileSync('test.pdf', file[0], 'binary')`

I've check the source code of both PDF and they are exactly the same.

What's the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
request({uri: 'test.pdf', headers: { 'Content-type' : 'applcation/pdf', 'encoding': null }} , function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    fs.writeFileSync("test.pdf", file[0], 'binary');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried and it's the same output... Doesn't work.